# UWP - FlipView - Need FlipView to only load a single item content

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, flipview

I have been struggling for the last week trying to implement a FlipView in the like of the Microsoft News UWP app.

I tried the following: a FlipView With an ItemTemplate and an ObservableCollection with my items.
However this caused the whole lot of items within my ObservableCollection to be pre-loaded, which is not what I want.

Has anyone got any tip allowing me to change this behaviour of the FlipView to be as follows: Only the first item is loaded, then when I click the arrow, the next item gets loaded.

Thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE:** 
I can confirm that the behaviour is as **@Sunteen Wu - MSFT** said.
I also tried using a similar logic to the one on fund the demo by **@Martin Zikmund**, however, it was not clearing the previous item

My goal is to load 1 single item at a time. The behaviour like so:
1) I see 1 item
2) If I click the **>** *(next)* arrow:
* this item is unloaded from the flipview
* the next item is loaded
3) if I click the **<** *(previous)* arrow:
* this item is unloaded from the flipview
* the previous item is re-loaded

Hope someone can help, I really want to give that feature to my users ^^.

Comment: Why are you concerned with it loading three items? This is a good thing. It allows best performance for your users and best memory usage as well

Answer (score 2):

> However this caused the whole lot of items within my ObservableCollection to be pre-loaded

[`FlipView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flipview.aspx) control's  `ItemsPanelTemplate` contains [`VirtualizingStackPanel`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.virtualizingstackpanel). So the `FlipView` control supports virtualization at default. You can check the visual tree when you debugging the app,  you may find no matter how many items you bind to the `FlipView`, it only load three `FlipViewItem` at default.

[image]

So in my opinion, the `FlipView` will not pre-loaded the whole items of your `ObservableCollection` , by default it may load the previous one, current one and the next one, unless you change the `ItemPanel` to `StackPanel` which doesn't support virtualization.

```
 <FlipView x:Name="flipView1" Width="480" Height="270" 
   BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
     <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
         <ItemsPanelTemplate>
             <StackPanel />
         </ItemsPanelTemplate>
     </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
     <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        ...
     </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
 </FlipView>
```

> Only the first item is loaded, then when I click the arrow, the next item gets loaded.

As `FlipView` using virtualization so that I guess you don't still need this feature. If you still want it, you can try to bind source to the `FlipView` with instance data is empty and every time the selection changed, force load the content manually. For this you may reference this [similar thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/flipview#dos-and-donts) that @Martin Zikmund provides a [demo](https://github.com/MartinZikmund/Stack-Overflow-2016/tree/master/LateLoadFlipView) for single loading.

Additionally, according to [Do's and don'ts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/flipview#dos-and-donts) remarks of FlipView:

> Avoid using a flip view control for larger collections, as the repetitive motion of flipping through each item can be tedious.

If you do have a larger collection for binding, avoid using a flip view but consider a  List view or grid view.

Comment: Hi Sunteen Wu, great explanation. When checking the VirtualizingStackPanel, there was 3 items as you said. I will investigate the demo from @Martin Zikmund, which seems to be what I would want. Thanks!

Comment: After using a similar logic from the demo by **@Martin Zikmund** (tailored for my own use), it still keeps previous items in cache, causing a weird behaviour. Previous items are kept in cache. I think I will try using a Pivot instead of a FlipView, and come back to you. Thanks for the help.